# Is it possible to run tests on a cpp file which already has a main function?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, c-preprocessor

Before I get the answer: "Move the code you wish to test to another .cpp file" I cannot do that. I have tried to use preprocessor `#if TESTING_SUITE ... #endif` but that does not work and I still get the:

> multiple definition of `main'

I compile my code like:

```
g++ -lmxml -lccpunit -o pic pic.cpp wmcc.cp test.cpp
```

I have one main in pic.cpp and the other in test.cpp. Is there a way around this?

**UPDATE**

In my test.cpp:

```
#define TESTING_SUITE_1
```

In my pic.cpp:

```
#ifndef TESTING_SUITE_1
    int main(...
#endif
```

Not working

Comment: You should be able to `#ifdef` out your existing `main()`. You probably did something wrong when you tried it. How did you do it?

Comment: Why can you not move `main` out to a different translation unit?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas because I have a lot of other source code which complicates it, this is just a tiny slice of the problem. I should have done that initially but I cannot now. BoBTFish i updated my Q

Comment: The size of the code does not matter that much, you just need to extract to a different translation unit one single function: `main`

Comment: I have a lot of other files, libraries, and linkage is what I meant but other source code. I cannot simply move it without breaking everything. Bad design, but I need a fix before I release a fixed version to port out the main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify another entry point to your linker.
For MS cl.exe either in code: (Sorry I didn't see you use gcc)

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:alternative_main")
```

or through the project property pages:

```
Configuration Properties >
  Linker >
    Advanced >
      Entry Point
```

or directly at the command line:

```
/entry:alternative_main
```

For gcc it's the following command line switch:

```
-Wl,-ealternative_main
```

For other compilers please refer to the handbook.

Comment: I get: multiple definition of `main`. Cannot find that in manpages, version?

Comment: `-Wl,option` passes `option` down to the linker (ld I assume). `-e` is a shortcut for `-entry` and specifies the entry point that the linker should use. These options are pretty standard and implemented since... I don't know, a very long time :p

Comment: oh, I understand now. I didn't change my `main` in test.cpp to `alternative_main` because I didn't understand - but after your explanation it was clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by compiling as

```
g++ -Dmain=main_pic_moved -c pic.cpp
g++ -Dmain=main_wmcc_moved -c wmcc.cp
g++ -lmxml -lccpunit -o pic pic.o wmcc.o test.cpp
```

Comment: I get: multiple definition of `main_pic_moved(int, char**). Looking into -Dmain though.

Comment: With those exact lines ? I can't see how this can happen.