# Calling main method from other project's main method in c++

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I want to call `main` method inside project `A` from `main` method inside project `B`. When I write in `B`'s `main.cpp`

```
    #include "pathToProjectA/main.cpp"
```

I get

```
    error C2084: function 'int main(int,char *[])' already has a body
```

Is it possible to make such call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't. Having one and only one `main()` is a hard design constraint.

You need to abstract your functionality into a function, possibly turn that into a library and then both A and B can use the new library.

Comment: Why this design constraint exist? It seems to me that is possible for compiler to know which main to call depending whether I call `A.exe` or `B.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply not possible. You can only have one main().

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two instances of `main()` function in one program. It would bring a big problem for the linker: Which one should be chosen as the *real* main function (called when launching the program)?

If you want to make two binaries (`A.exe` and `B.exe`) and call one of them from the other, you should read something about executing external processes. It is possible by using API of the OS or some platform-independent libraries (like Qt) but definitely not by calling the other process’ functions directly.

Answer (score -1):

The answers above aren't entirely true.

If it's okay with you to rename the `main` of your current project you can do that. Just rename it and tell the compiler to use your renamed main as entry point. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17868528/1825094).